# Figure caption not centered, but only for this figure

Tags: subcaption

I have a `figure` where I am placing three `subfigure`'s side by side.
Where I want the outer `figure` caption to be centered.
However, the captions keep being left-aligned and I cannot figure out why.
I use the `subcaption` package

What is weird to me is that I have other figures in the document which works just fine.
Following option a below.
What I have tried to fix the issue is the four options shown below.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Option a:**

```latex
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \missingfigure{}
    \caption{\label{fig:outline-skysat}Pansharpened Satellite images}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \missingfigure{}
    \caption{\label{fig:outline-xray-images}Grey scale X-Ray Images}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \missingfigure{}
    \caption{\label{fig:outline-raw-images}Object Images (RAW)}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{CAPTION}
\end{figure}
```

**Option b:**

```latex
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \missingfigure{}
    \caption{\label{fig:outline-skysat}Pansharpened Satellite images}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \missingfigure{}
    \caption{\label{fig:outline-xray-images}Grey scale X-Ray Images}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \missingfigure{}
    \caption{\label{fig:outline-raw-images}Object Images (RAW)}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{CAPTION}
\end{figure}
```

**Option c:**

```latex
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \missingfigure{}
    \caption{\label{fig:outline-skysat}Pansharpened Satellite images}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \missingfigure{}
    \caption{\label{fig:outline-xray-images}Grey scale X-Ray Images}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \missingfigure{}
    \caption{\label{fig:outline-raw-images}Object Images (RAW)}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{CAPTION}
\end{figure*}
```

**Option d:**

```latex
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \missingfigure{}
    \caption{\label{fig:outline-skysat}Pansharpened Satellite images}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \missingfigure{}
    \caption{\label{fig:outline-xray-images}Grey scale X-Ray Images}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \missingfigure{}
    \caption{\label{fig:outline-raw-images}Object Images (RAW)}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{CAPTION}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: it would be much easier to see the issue and test answers if you proved the example as a small but complete test document (you can use `example-image` for tests).  But the default caption formatting is centred if it fits in one line and a justified paragraph if not, so perhaps you are just seeing the effect of a longer text in some cases?

Comment: ... that might be it actually @DavidCarlisle

Comment: yup that was it... @DavidCarlisle Thank you, I did not know that there was this distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default caption formatting is centred if it fits in one line and a justified paragraph if not, so perhaps you are just seeing the effect of a longer text in some cases.